# mysql use of like and danish characters

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have a html form which - when posted - executes a SQL string in a Mysql db like this:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM IpProvider, IpUsers 
 WHERE IpProvider.UserId = IpUsers.Id AND 
 (IpProvider.CompanyName LIKE '%køb%' OR IpProvider.ShortDescrip LIKE '%køb%')
```

This returns 0 rows, but should return 1 row (as the danish word "køb" is part of the text in ShortDescrip). This search works fine with other text strings not holding danish characters.

The text directly copied from the table field:
`"Køb kvalitet fra starten - det er vores råd."`

Hmtl file holds a metatag stating: charset=utf-8

And the collation in the mysql table field is:
`utf8_general_ci`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to issue this query: `SET NAMES utf8;` at the beginning of your script. This will ensure that MySQL and your library "talk" UTF8 everywhere.

Also, try to change the collation for `utf8_unicode_ci`. This one is (supposedly) slower, although it handles better collations in some languages.

[Edit] My second advice might be irrelevant, as after reading again your question, you said that the search string appears "as is" in your db. I tend to use utf8_unicode_ci by default, though.

Comment: I have tried with mysql_set_charset - it now returns 1 row, even though the characters displayed are wrong, but I will figure that out - thanks a lot!

Comment: Stack is a question/answer website (quite different from a forum), you'll find advice about accepting an answer here: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the collation to latin1_danish_ci and see if thats better. Its possible the characters are sorted differently in latin1_danish_ci and utf8

Comment: Thanks for your input - I have tried that, it doesn't make any difference.